# Speed up vector-lookup for data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Per row in a data.table, I need to find the closest lower number from a vector. The following minimum working example does the job, but is much too slow, especially for longer pre.numbers vectors (about 1 million elements in the real data).

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(2)
pre.numbers <- sort(floor(runif(50000, 1, 1000000)))
the.table <- data.table(cbind(rowid=1:10000, current.number=floor(runif(1000, 1, 100000)), closest.lower.number=NA_integer_))
setkey(the.table, rowid)
the.table[, closest.lower.number:=max(pre.numbers[pre.numbers<current.number]), by=rowid]
```

There must be a smarter way to do it. There is no relationship between the vector-numbers and the numbers in the data.table.

Comment: You can reduce the problem size to a few rows for the _minimal_ example and use `set.seed` to make it reproducible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this? Using data.table's rolling joins:

```
DT = data.table(pre = pre.numbers, 
       current.number = pre.numbers+0.5, key="current.number")
setkey(the.table, current.number)
ans = DT[the.table, roll=Inf, rollends=FALSE]
```

Since you're dealing with integers, I've just added 0.5 (any number between 0 and 1 should be fine) to create `DT` from `pre.numbers`.

The last step performs a *LOCF rolling join* (last observation carried forward). For each value of `current.number` (key column), matching rows are looked for in `DT`'s `current.number` (key column). If there's no match, the last observation is rolled forward. And if the match occurs at the start/end, it results in `NA` (`rollends = FALSE`).

To illustrate better as to what happens, consider this case:

```
# pre.numbers:
# c(10, 11)

# the.table:
# current.numbers
#               9
#              10
#              11
```

We convert pre.numbers to `DT` first, which'll result in the columns

```
# DT:
# pre  current.numbers (key col)
#  10             10.5
#  11             11.5
```

For each value in `the.table`:

```
#  9 -> falls before 10.5, LOCF and rollends = FALSE => result is NA
# 10 -> falls before 10.5 => same as above
# 11 -> falls between 10.5 and 11.5, LOCF matches with previous row = 10.5 
#       corresponding pre = 10.
```

HTH

---

Here's the code I used to generate the data:

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(1L)
pre.numbers = sort(floor(runif(50000, 1, 1000000)))
the.table = data.table(rowid=1:10000, current.number=floor(runif(1000, 1, 100000)))
```

Comment: I was thinking exactly that but couldn't formulate the correct `roll` and `rollends` combination... rolling joins somewhat remains the hardest part to comprehend for me.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a vectorized solution:

```
algo1 = function()
{
    vec     = the.table$current.number
    indices = findInterval(vec-0.1, pre.numbers)
    res     = ifelse(indices==0, 0, vec[indices])

    the.table$closest.lower.number = res
}

algo2 = function()
{
    setkey(the.table, rowid)
    the.table[, closest.lower.number:=max(pre.numbers[pre.numbers<current.number]), by=rowid]
}
```

On my machine:

```
t1 = system.time(algo1())
#> t1
#user  system elapsed 
#0.0      0.0     0.0 

t2 = system.time(algo2())
#> t2
#user  system elapsed 
#9.73    0.00    9.73
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think this will catch closest lower or equal number. I strictly need closest lower (not equal), can it be modified for that?

Comment: @Chris Perhaps `findInterval(thetable$current.number*(1-.Machine$double.eps), pre.numbers)`

Comment: Humm findInterval(4-.Machine$double.eps, c(1,2,4,5)) returns 3. And the option of findInterval cant handle this point. I will edit my post.

Comment: Are you working just with integers? Or can it be any numeric?

Comment: Any numeric is ok, but I have no decimals. Thanks.

Comment: Ok so we can withdraw 0.1 to avoid this! What do you want as result if you have something in current.number like 4 and suppose pre.numbers=6:30000 ?

Comment: In that case, NA or 0

Comment: Not sure if its working, I get much bigger numbers now

Comment: It works ... what is the result if you have something in current number like 40000 and pre.numbers=6:30000 (the other case) ? And finally what do you mean by "much bigger numbers" ?